# Fix boot to console from boot to desktop

Tags: pi-3

I accidentally set it to boot to desktop (gui) instead of boot to console while fiddling with the settings. I don't have a gui installed. Now I cant access the pi over ssh to revert the settings on raspi-config.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you have physical (keyboard, monitor) access?

Comment: No, i dont have keyboard, monitor access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable ssh by putting a file called `ssh` (no extension) in the boot partition in the sdcard. Connect via ssh to the raspberry, then use `sudo raspi-config` to revert the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the RasPi to boot into any systemd target with a kernel parameter. For this you have to pull out the SD Card from your RasPi and modify it on another computer. To `cmdline.txt` in the boot partition append this:

```
 systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Then it should boot to the console login. I don't know if this also makes ssh available again but it's worth a try.